# conversion from nvarchar to numeric fails

Tags: sql, t-sql

I am trying to execute this query but the following error is occurring:

```
Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric
```

this is my query :

```
Select Top 20 *,dbo.GetDistance(35.5,33.8, Longitude, Latitude) as Distance 
From ViewBranchCoordinates
order by Distance desc
```

if i remove this line `order by Distance desc` the query run normally with no error

this is the function `GetDistance`

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[GetDistance] 
(
-- Add the parameters for the function here
  @Long decimal(30,24), @Lat decimal(30,24), @Long2 decimal(30,24), @Lat2   decimal(30,24)
)
--decimal(8,6), @Long)
RETURNS decimal(38,28)
AS
BEGIN
-- Declare the return variable here
DECLARE @Distance decimal(38,28)
DECLARE @valueOne decimal(30,24)
DECLARE @valueTwo decimal(30,24)
DECLARE @dLat decimal(30,24)
DECLARE @dLng decimal(30,24)
DECLARE @SectionOne decimal(30,24)
DECLARE @SectionTwo decimal(30,24)

Select @dLat = RADIANS(@Lat - @Lat2)
Select @dLng = RADIANS(@Long -  @Long2)
Select @SectionOne = square(sin((@dLat)/2))
Select @SectionTwo = cos(RADIANS(@Lat)) *  cos(RADIANS(@Lat2)) * square(sin(@dLng / 2))
Select @valueOne =CONVERT(decimal(30,24),@SectionOne + @SectionTwo) 
Select @valueTwo = 2 * ATN2(SQRT(@valueOne), SQRT(1 - @valueOne))
Select @Distance = 6371000 * @valueTwo

RETURN @Distance

END
```

Any help please

Comment: maybe `order by dbo.GetDistance(35.5,33.8, Longitude, Latitude) desc` for the order part.

Comment: i tired it, it return the same error

Comment: did you try the DECLARE and SELECT block by itself with some default Lat and Long? It seems the the error might be here :CONVERT(decimal(30,24),@SectionOne + @SectionTwo)

Comment: Are Longitude, Latitude stored as `nvarchar`? If so why? But looks like there might be invalid data there.

Comment: Without the `order by`, this is "perform the distance calculation for 20 non-specific rows" and you are happening to get lucky. With the `order by`, and specifically where it's based on the *result* of your calculation, it's "perform the distance calculation for *all* rows" and then work out which 20 to select. So, you have duff data in there. We can't really help you much further - you're the one with the data.

Comment: sample Latitude and Longitude values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I presume this will fail too?

```
 Select Top 20 *
 ,dbo.GetDistance(35.5,33.8, cast (Longitude as decimal (30,24)), cast(Latitude as (30,24)) as Distance 
 From ViewBranchCoordinates
```

Your function expects data of a certain type. If your lat/long columns are nvarchar then non numeric data can be in those columns.

Search for problem data, e.g.

```
Select *
From ViewBranchCoordinates
Where try_cast (longitude as numeric) IS NULL
```

Then you need to fix the data.

Comment: Making the conversion explicit rather than implicit doesn't change whether the conversion can succeed or not. And if you're assuming the existence of `TRY_CAST`, I'd be seriously wondering why they're not just using in-build geographic types (which were introduced earlier than `TRY_CAST`) rather than doing all of this by hand.

Comment: Exactly. Nor can I  account for why lat long is nvarchar.

Comment: we found out that the error is in the view it self and updated and now it is working thank yo u

Comment: Great. Do take damien's advice about the data types. There are specific types that will help in data validity and performance.